# What are the most reliable attributes for comparing two files in order to confirm/verify they are 100% identical?

Tags: diff, checksum, file-attributes, file-comparison

I had the following situation:

I copied `5.5 TB` worth of data (in total over 100,000 directories and 10 million files) from an old disk to a newly-purchased external disk.

I used `Ultracopier` on `Windows 10` to do the entire copy and I had the **`Verify checksums`** option enabled in order to have the checksum of each and every file verified after the copy.

Next I used `TreeSize` and `SpaceSniffer` and verified that the total size of the backed up directories and the number of files and directories are exactly the same on the old and new drive.

Finally, I used `Beyond Compare 4` which **supposedly** compares all attributes of files and folders with each other (size, dates, etc.). It is also capable of `binary comparison`. It reported that the data on the old and new drive are exactly identical even after `binary comparison`.

My **question** is threefold:

1. Was the above approach reliable and comprehensive enough to conclude that the data is indeed identical on both drives and there were no errors/mess-ups during the copy process?
2. What is the best and most reliable file attribute and/or approach for comparing two files? Is a `checksum` really enough? Or a `binary comparison`?
3. How likely is it, in such a huge transfer of files, to end up with a few corrupted or partially copied files? **Especially** when `Verify checksums` was enabled. Is such a scenario likely at all, *ever*?

RELATED: [Is verifying a MD5 sum after copying 100GB of data safe?](https://superuser.com/questions/293271/is-verifying-a-md5-sum-after-copying-100gb-of-data-safe)

Comment: Well your new drive could develop an error after all of the files have been successfully copied ... otherwise I think you are safe.

Comment: To interpret what they said over at the “related” question: If you’re worried about a random I/O error encountered in the copy process, checksums are 99.9999…% good enough.  If you’re worried that some very powerful, resourceful entity (like a national agency or a crime syndicate) maliciously replaced one of your files, do a binary compare.  But it won’t work, because they will have installed malware on your system to make the file compare software not work correctly.     :-)     ⁠

Comment: The basic checksum could do it, but a stronger, more complex hash check such as `sha256sum`, would be better.  Take a heck of a lot longer to verify as well...